# Windows Phone 8 Reminder with a custom recurrence interval

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there any way to get a `Reminder` to work on a custom recurrence interval, like every 4 hours? Because the only option now that I know of is to set the `RecurrenceType` to `RecurrenceInterval`, which only supports daily, weekly, monthly and yearly recurrences.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Everything I can find says that same thing - It has to be daily, weekly, monthly, or yearly. You may try setting a bunch of `Reminder`s up. It's hokey but the best I can come up with.

Comment: Yep, I found out the same. Yeah I'm probably gonna set up a bunch of Reminders, it's a hack but it must be done somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way to repeat reminder in every 4 hours for specific number of time:

```
    private int _intervalHours;
    public int IntervalHours
    {
        get
        {
            return _intervalHours;
        }
        set
        {
            _intervalHours = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IntervalHours");
        }
    }

    private int _frequency;
    public int Frequency
    {
        get
        {
            return _frequency;
        }
        set
        {
            _frequency = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Frequency");
        }
    }
      //RecurrenceInterval.None is used as a new reminder will be created for every 4  hours in your case
      RecurrenceInterval recurrence = RecurrenceInterval.None;

      //inserting staring reminder
      name = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      reminder = new Reminder(name);
      reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
      reminder.Title = title;
      reminder.Content = content;
      reminder.BeginTime = beginTime;
      reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
      reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
      reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;
      ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);

       //inserting reminder for IntervalHours, let say at interval of 4 hours and will added after each IntervalHours upto Frequency(number of time)
       if (IntervalHours > 0)
        {
            //i is started from 1 as 1 reminder added above
            for (int i = 1; i < Frequency; i++)
            {                    
                name = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                reminder = new Reminder(name);
                reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
                reminder.Title = title;
                reminder.Content = content;
                reminder.BeginTime = beginTime.AddHours(IntervalHours*i);
                reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime.AddHours(IntervalHours*i);
                reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
                reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;
                ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I did exactly that, check my comment on the question. But I will accept your answer, since it is the right one.

Answer (score -1):

Currently in WP8 it doesn't support.